# Show that :(a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n+1})$ is a convergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that :
(a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n+1})$ is a convergent series.

(b) If $|f'(x)|<1 $ for all $x \in (0,1)$, show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n+1})|$ is a convergent series.

My try.
(a) is more or less easy as it telescopes to $f(1)-f(\frac{1}{n+1})$ which on taking $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} $ becomes $f(1)-f(0)$.But one question, I have to prove $f(1)-f(0)$ to be finite.

(b) We have $-1<f'(x)<1$ .Integrating from $0$ to $x$ , we have  $-x<f(x)-f(0)<x \implies |f(x)-f(0)|<x $.Plugging $x=\frac{1}{n}$, we have $|f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)|<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$, So $f(\frac{1}{n})$ converges to $f(0)$.From here can we say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n+1})|$ is a convergent series?

Answer (score 1):

You may apply Mean Value Theorem to your second question. For your first question, definitely it is finite, the function $f$ is just real-valued.

Mean Value Theorem is used in this way: So for each $n$, some $\xi_{n}$ in between $1/n$ and $1/(n+1)$ is such that $|f(1/n)-f(1/(n+1))|=|f'(\xi_{n})|(1/n-1/(n+1))\leq(1/n-1/(n+1))$, summing up we get $\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f(1/n)-f(1/(n+1))|\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n}(1/n-1/(n+1))=1<\infty$.

Comment: Can you explain how Mean value theorem helps?

Comment: More generally, the MVT can be used to show that any differentiable function with bounded derivative is Lipschitz (which is really what we care about here).

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{n=1} \left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left( \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \right]= f(1)-f\left(\frac{1}{N+1} \right)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left( \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \right]=&\ \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum^N_{n=1} \left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left( \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \right]\\
=&\ \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\left[f(1)-f\left(\frac{1}{N+1} \right) \right] = f(1)-f(0)<\infty
\end{align}
which follows from the fact $f$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$.

Next, observe
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{n=1}\left| f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left( \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right| =&\ \sum^N_{n=1}\left| \int^{1/n}_{1/(n+1)}f'(x)\ dx \right|\\
\leq \sum^N_{n=1} \int^{1/n}_{1/(n+1)}|f'(x)|\ dx \leq&\ \sum^N_{n=1} \left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right] = 1-\frac{1}{N+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Only  one point I need to clarify we are showing that $\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f(1/n)-f(1/(n+1))|\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n}(1/n-1/(n+1))=1<\infty$. , it is just telling us that the series is $\le 1$. But how can we tell that it converges?

Comment: You are summing up positive terms.

Comment: The partial sums are increasing and bounded.